# Test fixture with JUnit - array illegal start of expression

Tags: java, bluej

I can't seem to fix this problem.

My code starts like this :

```
public class Aandeel
{
private String code;
private String naam;
private double dividend;
private double[] waarden;

public Aandeel(String code, String naam, double dividend, double[] tab)
{
    this.code = code;
    this.naam = naam;
    setDividend(dividend);
    waarden = new double[12];
    setWaarden(tab);
}
```

There is no problem there. But if I create a test class for this class, 
after that I make an object "aandeel1".
If I right-click on the test class and then move the objects in the class as a starting texture, my code won't compile with the error "illegal start of expression" and points to the values inserted as a paramater.
You can see it in the following code between **:

```
public class AandeelTest
{
private Aandeel aandeel1;

/**
 * Constructor voor test class AandeelTest
 */
public AandeelTest()
{
}

/**
 * Opzetten van de test fixture.
 *
 * Aanroep voor elke test case method.
 */
@Before
public void setUp()
{
    aandeel1 = new Aandeel("AUG", "AUgurance", 4.5, **{1.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0}**);
}

/**
 * Verwijderen van de test fixture.
 *
 * Aanroep na elke test case method.
 */
@After
public void tearDown()
{
}
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to pass a double array :

```
aandeel1 = new Aandeel("AUG", "AUgurance", 4.5, new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0});
```